# How to see the classes generated by lombok in maven spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, lombok, sts

I am trying to use lombok in my application which is based on spring boot and maven configuration.

I have added the dependency:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>1.18.16</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

in my pom.xml. Also as I am using STS, I have installed Lombok into my sts by running the jar. I am able to use Lombok annotations and use the getters, setters, etc. but I am not able to see my generated classes/methods in `target/generated-sources` folder.

Is there a particular reason, why I am not able to see those generated classes and how STS or maven is able to use these generated classes/methods?

Can any one help me understand? And if possible how to view those generated classes/methods?

**Note**: My source code folder is still `src/main/java` only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your project compiled class files are located in the **target/classes** folder.
This folder is not visible in the default view i.e., **Package Explorer** view. You need to enable the **Navigator** (now deprecated) view from ***Window -> Show View*** to see the contents of the target folder. Once done, your compiled classes will be visible in the **target/classes** folder according to your project package structure.

Comment: so the class generated by lombok will also be available in the target/classes folder right?

Comment: Yes. And you can use a decompiler plugin to see the generated getter and setter method for your class fields.

Answer (score 2):

Lombok doesn't work by outputting source into `target/generated-sources`; that technique only allows adding new source files, not modifying the classes being compiled. Lombok instead works by hacking into the compiler internals and messing with the compilation process itself.

Comment: got it.Thank you

Comment: Also unrelated but is it safe to use the lombok generated equals, hashcode methods?

Comment: @happytohelp What do you mean by "safe"? Major frameworks used by developers all over the world use them, so I don't have any reservations about doing so.